# Setting values of Angular Reactive form from disabled inputs

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, disabled-input

my problem is that have 2 disabled inputs inside my reactive form but I want my form to still get their values.
They have values because they are set with functions : findStudentLastName() findStudentFirstName() which take the value of the input `<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Identifiant" required formControlName="id" list="id" #ref>`.

Hope you can help me.

Here a part of my form :

```html
            <div formArrayName="students">
                <div style="margin-top:5px; margin-bottom:5px;"
                    *ngFor="let student of classForm.get('students')['controls']; let i=index">
                    <hr>
                    <legend>
                        <h4>Etudiant(e) {{i+1}} :</h4>
                    </legend>
                    <fieldset>
                        <div [formGroupName]="i">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger float-right" style="margin-top:32px;"
                                (click)="deleteStudent(i)">
                                <i class="fas fa-trash-alt" style="font-size: 20px;" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                            </button>
                            <div class="form-group form-row">
                                <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
                                    <label>Identifiant</label>
                                    <div class="input-group">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Identifiant" required
                                            formControlName="id" list="id" #ref>
                                        <datalist id="id">
                                            <option *ngFor="let idS of studentsArr | keyvalue" value="{{idS.key}}"></option>
                                        </datalist>  
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
                                    <label>First name</label>

                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="firstname" formControlName="firstname" [value]="findStudentFirstName(ref.value)" required [attr.disabled]="true">

                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
                                    <label>Last name</label>

                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="lastname" formControlName="lastname" [value]="findStudentLastName(ref.value)" required [attr.disabled]="true">


                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </fieldset>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Here a part of my TS :

```js
    data = {
        name: "",
        students: [
            {
                id: "",
                firstname: "",
                lastname:""
            }
        ]
    }

    studentsArr: Record <string, [string, string]> = {
        jhdoe: ["Jhon","DOE"],
        jadoe: ["Jane","DOE"],
        adurand: ["Albert","DURAND"]
    }

    findStudentFirstName(id: string):string {
        if(this.studentsArr[id] != undefined) {
            return this.studentsArr[id][0];
        }
    }
    findStudentLastName(id: string):string {
        if(this.studentsArr[id] != undefined) {
            return this.studentsArr[id][1];
        }
    }
    constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
        this.classForm = this.fb.group({
            name: ['', Validators.required],
            students: this.fb.array([])
        })
        this.setStudents();
    }
    setStudents() {
        let control = <FormArray>this.classForm.controls.students;
        this.data.students.forEach(x => {
            control.push(this.fb.group({
                id: x.id,
                firstname: x.firstname,
                lastname: x.lastname
            }))
        })
    }
    addNewStudent() {
        let control = <FormArray>this.classForm.controls.students;
        control.push(
            this.fb.group({
                id: ['', Validators.required],
                firstname: ['', Validators.required],
                lastname: ['', Validators.required]
            })
        )
        $('.toastS').toast('show');
        $(document).ready(function () { $(document).scrollTop($(document).height()) });
    }
```

What I get when i enter a correct "id" of student :
[image: here]

What I want to have when i enter a correct student "id" :

```
{
  "name": "",
  "students": [
    {
      "id": "jadoe",
      "firstname": "Jane",
      "lastname": "DOE"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: You can use getRawValue() method to get the entire form data along with the disabled form items

Comment: If you don't know how to use it.. you can refer this blog: https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroup#getRawValue

Comment: Hi @sunilbaba thanks for the awnser but getRawValue() doesn't change anything unfortunatly, even if enable my inputs it still doesn't work until I start typing something inside them.

Comment: What is the event you are looking where you want to get the disabled form values ?

Comment: Actually I just want my form to recognize the firstname and lastname value which I set with a function just like it was the user typing in the input.
Those values are linked with the form thanks to the formControlName directive.
It totatly works when I type something into those inputs but not when I set a value in it with a function.

Comment: There is a another built in function in angular form called listenToValueChanges which will be called when ever there is a change in form value irrespective it was set by the function or user input. If you subscribe to this method you will be able to listen to value changes and get the raw form data inside it

Comment: How can I use this function ? I searched on internet for this name "listenToValueChanges" but I only find one called "onValueChanges".

Comment: https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControlDirective#valueChanges

Comment: Value change is the method name .. listen to value changes by using that method.. so my bad space was missing

Comment: I tried this method but it wasn't working either ( maybe i'm using it the wrong way ) BUT i find myself a solution to my problem i'm going to post as an awnser.
Thanks for trying to help me @sunilbaba

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i finnaly find a solution to my problem.

In my previous code I was getting the value of this input : `<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Identifiant" required formControlName="id" list="id" #ref>`

and using it as a parameter of a function to set the **firstname** and **lastname** input **value** of a **students** entry `<input type="text" class="form-control" name="firstname" formControlName="firstname" [value]="findStudentFirstName(ref.value)" required [attr.disabled]="true">`

but it wasn't changing the value in the form ( only the actual input value ) ... so I create a new function and remove the others from my lastname and firstname inputs :

```js
    applyNames() {
        const formLines = this.classForm.get('students') as FormArray;
        formLines.controls.forEach(control =>  { 
            control.get('firstname').setValue(this.findStudentFirstName(control.get('id').value));
            control.get('lastname').setValue(this.findStudentLastName(control.get('id').value))
        });
    }
```

and use it in the first input :
`<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Identifiant" required formControlName="id" list="id" (input)="applyNames()">`

And this way it actually change both the value in the input and the value in the form.